# Regex to make sure that in a text field there is exactly two semicolons (;) per line

Tags: regex

In a form on my website I have a text box where people have to write information about their past jobs on the following format:

```
Job; Title; Years on the job
```

So when they write many jobs in the form, they can add any number of jobs

```
   A Job; A title; A number of years
   Another Thing; More here; something else again
   Another Job; More Titles; Another Number of Years
```

They can write any number of lines they want, but I want to make sure everything they write is according to the asked format.

**What is the regex to make sure that a given string contains exactly 2 semi-colons per line?**

Comment: In this case why you didn't provide 3 input fields with a `+` button to add a new entry? Problem solved, no?

Comment: I wish I could do that... But I am using Qualtrics... which is a survey tool that doesn't allow me to do that...

Comment: I don't know Qualtrics, but I don't think it's a problem, once you get the data you are free to format them as you want, don't you?

Comment: Unfortunately it has been proven that when I don't force a certain way of responding people do whatever they want.... And the idea is to automate this... Of course I can do it manually, but I can't automate it unless I have a strict format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
^([^\r\n;]*;[^\r\n;]*;[^\r\n;]*(\r?\n|$))*$
```

[RegEx tester](https://regex101.com/r/pM8qX2/1)

This regular expression matches either all or nothing.

Comment: Did you actually test that it fails, when the condition is not met? Especially test it with 2 lines which contain a single semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that. Corrected.

Comment: It's almost perfect... But it doesn't work when I have no semicolon in the second line or when I have an empty line

Comment: I would also use `+` instead of `*`, as I guess an empty job/title/year should be invalid too.